# Worries about ability

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, proof-of-stake

I have never been the best at math. However I am pretty good with computers. If I buy the gear to mine the coin how hard is it to work the machinery and do the work to make the coin?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this question, it seems like you did not research bitcoin mining enough.

At this point, mining bitcoin is not profitable for the average user unless you have close to zero electricity fees and a pretty powerful computer to start with.

The bitcoin difficulty is always going up, making any investment into hardware obsolete. Most mining farms are in China due to these reasons.

You yourself do not solve math problems when mining, instead you computer will solve mathematical puzzles that the bitcoin network gives it. The faster you find the key to the puzzle (you need a fast computer) the more coins you may mine. At this point, the profitability for bitcoin mining is close to zero for the average user.

Comment: Well my computer is far from average. There is only one i7 out there that is better than the one I have. And I think 32 gig's of ram should do it. But I can get up to 64 in no time.

Comment: Is mining other cryptocurrency profitable?

Comment: Joshua, most mining these days is done by [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit)s, not general-purpose CPUs. "Puzzle" solving is a misnomer for the proof-of-work that mining requires. It's just tedious (for a human) repetitive binary arithmetic: find the value, which, when input to a procedure operating on a given set of data, produces a desired output. There's no way to make any educated guesses about the input value, so the program has to just start with the lowest (or highest) possible and keep incrementing (or decrementing) it until success.

Comment: All personal computer systems in the world combined would only be able to produce a tiny amount of BTC. Having a fast computer is irrelevant. All mining now happens on specialized hardware that is many orders of magnitude faster at hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua, mining cryptocurrency these days involves much more than a single CPU home computer.

Have a look at https://vimeo.com/165840295 from genesis mining. No endorsement from my side though. It should just give you the impression about the scale of hardware.

Unless you are able to heavily invest, conventional mining (at least bitcoin) is not profitable these days.

However, you may consider alternative ideas like distributed mining networks using green energy etc...